# Get username out of user ID

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Multisite Installation i get the user id with:

```
$user_ID
```

and it works fine in my subsite (subdomain). My users can only log in from the mainsite and i didnt figure out how to get the username when the user is logged in and visits the subsite (subdomain) But the User ID works fine...

I need the name of the user? Any way to filter the name out of the user ID - so i get the name of the user instead of the user id number?

Thank you so much

Comment: I'll let the gurus figure this one out with that one-liner of yours. Personally, I could never "Name that Tune" from just a single note ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `get_user_by(...)` Function, that returns a [WP_User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) instance that you can then use to extract the User Name.

```
<?php $user = get_user_by( $field, $value ); ?>
```

So you would call it like so

```
<?php $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_ID ); ?>
```

You can also try the `wp_get_current_user` function ([click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) ) that return details about the currently logged in user, including the full name.

```
<?php global $current_user;
      wp_get_current_user();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
      echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
      echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
      echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thx... But i try to create a url with the username:) $current_user->user_login  echos the right name - any idea how to transform this code: " <?php echo network_home_url('/' . $wp_rewrite->author_base . '/') . $user_ID; ?> " to get this url: example.com/user/nameoftheuser  ??? i only miss the last part of the url - the name of the user... Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked out. When you solve it yourself, you remember it forever :)